# Continuity for multivariate function

Tags: real-analysis

I have a very quick question:

If I have a function like $f(x,y) = (3,y)$, can I claim that this function is continuous on some specified domain because we have the projections $(x,y) ↦ 3$ and $(x,y) ↦ y$ which are continuous? Or could I just claim that the components are continuous, hence the function is continuous?

(Sorry if this seems like a silly post, but I am new to multivariable functions)

Comment: Yes, for continuity it is enough that components be continuous.

Comment: Yes, this is a valid argument. However, do try to clarify for yourself *why* it is valid. (What do you know about convergence in $\mathbb R^2$.)

Comment: I'd just like to suggest that the right home for the notion of continuity is in the subject of general topology. Do try to learn it if your have the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given two metric spaces $(X,d_{X})$, $(Y,d_{Y})$ and a function $f:X\to Y$, we say that $f$ is continuous iff for every $\varepsilon > 0$, and every $x_{0}\in X$ there corresponds a $\delta > 0$ such that
\begin{align*}
x\in X,\,d_{X}(x,x_{0}) < \delta \Rightarrow d_{Y}(f(x),f(x_{0})) < \varepsilon
\end{align*}

At your case $X = Y = \textbf{R}^{2}$. Then your problem can be rephrased as:

Is $f:\textbf{R}^{2}\to\textbf{R}^{2}$ given by $f(x,y) = (3,y)$ continuous?

In order to answer it, we shall consider the euclidean metric $d_{2}(x,a) = \sqrt{(x_{1} - a_{1})^{2} + (x_{2} - a_{2})^{2}}$.

Moreover, we do also have that $|x_{2} - a_{2}| \leq d_{2}(x,a) = \sqrt{(x_{1} - a_{1})^{2} + (x_{2} - a_{2})^{2}}$.

Thus, for every $\varepsilon > 0$ and every $a\in\textbf{R}^{2}$, there corresponds a $\delta = \varepsilon$ such that for every $x\in\textbf{R}^{2}$, we have
\begin{align*}
|x_{2} - a_{2}| \leq d_{2}(x,a) < \delta \Rightarrow 
d_{2}(f(x),f(a)) = \sqrt{(3-3)^{2} + (x_{2} - a_{2})^{2}} = |x_{2} - a_{2}| < \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Hence $f$ is continuous, just as desired, and we are done.

**BONUS**

As suggested, it can be proven that $f:\textbf{R}^{n}\to\textbf{R}^{n}$ given by $f(x) = (f_{1}(x),f_{2}(x),\ldots,f_{n}(x))$ is continuous iff $f_{i}:\textbf{R}^{n}\to\textbf{R}$ is continuous for every $1\leq i\leq n$. With the purpose of doing so, we will equip $\textbf{R}^{n}$ with the euclidean metric, given by
\begin{align*}
d_{2}(x,y) = \sqrt{(x_{1} - y_{1})^{2} + (x_{2} - y_{2})^{2} + \ldots + (x_{n} - y_{n})^{2}}
\end{align*}

Indeed, let us suppose that $f$ is continuous. This means that for every $a\in\textbf{R}^{n}$ and every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for $x\in\textbf{R}^{n}$, one has that
\begin{align*}
d_{2}(x,a) < \delta \Rightarrow d_{2}(f(x),f(a)) < \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Since $|f_{i}(x) - f_{i}(a)| \leq d_{2}(f(x),f(a))$, we conclude that for every $1\leq i \leq n$ one has that
\begin{align*}
d_{2}(x,a) < \delta \Rightarrow |f_{i}(x) - f_{i}(a)| < \varepsilon
\end{align*}

That is to say, $f_{i}(x)$ is continuous.

Conversely, if each coordinate function $f_{i}(x)$ is continuous, for every $a\in\textbf{R}^{n}$ and every $\varepsilon/n > 0$, there corresponds a $\delta_{i} > 0$ such that for every $x\in\textbf{R}^{n}$, one has that
\begin{align*}
d_{2}(x,a) < \delta_{i} \Rightarrow |f_{i}(x) - f_{i}(a)| < \varepsilon/n
\end{align*}

Once the following inequality holds
\begin{align*}
d_{2}(f(x),f(a)) \leq |f_{1}(x) - f_{1}(a)| + |f_{2}(x) - f_{2}(a)| + \ldots + |f_{n}(x) - f_{n}(a)|
\end{align*}
if we choose $\delta = \min\{\delta_{1},\delta_{2},\ldots,\delta_{n}\}$, it results that
\begin{align*}
d_{2}(x,a) < \delta \Rightarrow d_{2}(f(x),f(a)) \leq |f_{1}(x) - f_{1}(a)| + \ldots + |f_{n}(x) - f_{n}(a)| < \varepsilon
\end{align*}
whence we conclude that $f$ is continuous.